# DEL key of Keyboard does not work

Tags: keyboard, delete, text-editor

I tried searching in the forum but could not find any solution to my problem.

When I press <kbd>Delete</kbd> (as in text-editor), it does not do anything. I would like it to perform its usual functionality, like deleting the next character or symbol while typing. I am using Ubuntu. The rest of the keyboard works as it is supposed to.

Thank you

(is any more information required?)

Comment: Please provide relevant information, such as Ubuntu version, Computer brand and/or model and/or make. Also, which text editor did you encounter this issue in? And lastly, does  this happen only on the said text editor, or it is global?

Comment: Hi, i use Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS and have a Lenovo 910 Yoga. I've tried to use LibreOffice. After your question I've discovered that it does not work anywhere. So it's a global problem. Thank you

Comment: After updating the linux it now works! Had some issues with public keys etc. so after I got that sorted out it suddenly worked. Don't know if that was the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, same solution. Update all and restart has solved it.